# UIGestureRecognizer setState: in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I'm converting some legacy Obj C code to swift. I was trying to subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` and use the `setState:` method.
When I do:

```
class MyGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    // ...

    func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.state = .failed
    }

}
```

I get an error saying:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'state' is a get-only property
```

So I added an extension overriding `state` property:

```
extension MyGestureRecognizer {

    override var state: UIGestureRecognizerState {
        get {
            return self.state
        }
        set {
            self.state = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Now, the code runs, but I have weird runtime `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` exceptions at `return self.state` in the extension.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28395135/1187415: add `import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass`

Comment: See also https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer:  Subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer must import UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h. This header file contains a redeclaration of state that makes it read-write.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. I should've read the docs first.